# The Weight of Air A Human has to Bear

Tags: atmospheric-science, weight

The average circumference of the human chest is $97$cm to $114 cm$. Let us, for the sake of simplicity, assume that this is a circle. The cross-sectional area of the human body then is $\approx 3 \times \left(\frac{0.97}{6}\right)^2 =0.08 \space m^2$  (taking the lower limit $97$ cm)

The atmosphere extends roughly $12$ km vertically = $12000$ m

The volume of air then, pressing on top of our bodies, is = $0.08 \times 12000 = 960 \space m^3$

The density of air is roughly $1 \space kg/m^3$

So the weight of the air an average person has to bear = $1 \times 960 = 960 \space kg$.

How come we don't feel this $960$ kg weight ($9408$ Newtons) of air?

Comment: Can be helpful : https://www.wtamu.edu/~cbaird/sq/2015/09/14/why-dont-i-feel-the-miles-of-air-above-me-that-are-crushing-me-down/

Comment: What do you mean by "feel"? This pressure is the *normal* state of affairs for organisms living on the surface of the earth, it would be pretty weird if we had evolved to constantly notice it.

Comment: What you've got there is [spherical cow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow) model of a human.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of why we don't feel the weight of the atmosphere pressing down on us, it's important to understand the fundamental concept of why we feel the weight of objects in the first place. The sensation of weight is a result of the force of gravity acting on an object. When we pick up a heavy object, we feel its weight because gravity is pulling it down, and our bodies must exert a force equal to the weight of the object to support it. This is why we experience a sensation of weight when lifting or carrying something heavy.

However, the case of the Earth's atmosphere is different.

The equilibrium means there is no net force acting on our bodies due to atmospheric pressure. The internal forces in our bodies, such as blood pressure in our veins, are already in equilibrium with the external atmospheric pressure.

Moreover, humans have evolved over millions of years to live in Earth's atmospheric conditions, and our bodies have adapted to withstand this pressure without us consciously feeling it as mentioned in the comments by @ACuriousMind. Therefore, while the weight of the atmosphere is indeed significant when calculated in terms of force (Newtons), we don't perceive it as a heavy weight because the pressure is evenly distributed, both inside and outside our bodies, leading to an overall equilibrium of forces. So, the sensation of weight is typically associated with imbalances in forces, which is not the case with the evenly distributed atmospheric pressure that surrounds us.